# How to add value into input type date Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Well, I have this HTML code:

```html
<input type="date" name="start_date" value="<?php echo date(" Y-m-d "); ?>"/>
<input type="date" name="finish_date" value="5"/>
```

I need to do the calculation below when **start_date** or **finish_date** object value changed

```
start_date + finish_date = final_date
```

I don't know how to do the calculation above in Javascript.

**Final date** formatted in date value by the way, for example: *2016-12-18 + 5 = 2016-12-23*

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So, parse the date from the input (that's very well-covered here on SO) and then add a day to it (also very well-covered here on SO) and format the resulting data (you guessed it, well-covered here on SO) and put that string back in the input.

Comment: _start_date + finish_date = final_date_ ??? So 2016-01-15 + 2016-01-15 = 4032-02-30 ???

Comment: @baao Final date formatted in date value by the way, for example: 2016-12-18 + 5 = 2016-12-23

Comment: So, `finish_date` is actually a number of days?

Comment: @MaxArt Yes. correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert both the dates to timestamps, add the timestamps and construct a new date.

```
// this is milliseconds
var time_stamp = start_date.getTime() 

var finish_stamp = finish_date.getTime()

var final_date = new Date(time_stamp + finish_stamp);
```

Comment: I want to add duration in days to final_date where final_date = start_date(input type date) + finish_date(also input type date)

Comment: `var final_date = new Date(start_date.getTime() + finish_date.getTime());` something like this could work

Comment: Pardon me, finish_date is not input type date but input type text, its contain days value in number.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you want:

```
var startDate = document.querySelector("[name=start_date]");
var finishDate = document.querySelector("[name=finish_date]");

var start = startDate.valueAsDate;
var days = parseInt(finishDate.value);

var finalDate = new Date(start);
finalDate.setDate(finalDate.getDate() + days);

var fomattedDate = finalDate.getFullYear()
    + ("0" + (finalDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
    + ("0" + finalDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
// Or, if the browser supports toISOString:
var formattedDate = finalDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

A note: name your fields and variables with meaningful terms. If you call `finish_date` what's *not* a date but actually a number, everybody gets confused.